# How do I Switch off NFC?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, nfc

My Nexus S alerts me when it is close to my Oyster season ticket.
It says New Tag Collected. Unknown tag type.

Can I stop it doing this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Gingerbread User Guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/googlephone/AndroidUsersGuide-2.3.pdf), under **Settings** -> **Wireless & networks**, you should have an **NFC** option that you can remove the tick from to turn this on or off.