# Unknown Tag Type collection

Tags: settings, nfc

Since purchasing my Samsung Nexus S I have been bombarded by 'New Tag Collected' Tag Type 'Unknown'.

I have since learned how to turn this off, but I was wondering what these Tags are and where are they coming from?

Comment: For anyone who hasn't yet learnt how to turn this off, see this other question How do I Switch off NFC? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/how-do-i-switch-off-nfc

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like NFC terminology to me.  Presumably either NFC is malfunctioning or you've been in the vicinity of NFC tags that are of a type your phone doesn't recognize.

Looks like ID badges and probably some credit cards and so on could trigger this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-989630.html

Comment: Looks like this previous question has someone getting this exact message when their phone is near their Oyster Card (contact-less public transport payment card used in London), so it looks like you're right, especially as some banks are starting to also embed these in their credit cards now too.

Answer (score 2):

I had just activated my new credit card and it was sitting beside my Nexus S and this kept happening. After reading this I tested it and it was the credit card causing it to happen.

Comment: you can search and buy protection sleeves ( https://www.google.de/search?q=credit+card+protection+sleeve ). If you wonder what kind of data can be read without protection sleeves: Pretty much, a german researcher recently published a small app that showed it (it got booted both from github and google play though).